# Selective upgrade of ios firmware

Tags: iphone, upgrade, firmware

I have IPhone 4 running with Version 5.1.1 (9B206)
I would like to update the firmware, but not to the current latest version (7.1.1) which is known to be slow on IPhone 4.

In the phone settings I can only choose the latest available firmware version.
Is there a way to update the phone to an earlier version such as 6 ?

Comment: that would result in no compatible ios and firmware?

Comment: [Dupe of quite a few questions](http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=update+iPhone+4+ios+6); which one is this closest to?